# How to make manifold stream with dropping buffer?

Tags: clojure, core.async

Using `core.async` I'm able to easily create a channel with dropping buffer:

```
(async/chan (async/dropping-buffer 10))
```

Is it possible to create [`manifold`](https://github.com/ztellman/manifold) stream with dropping buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same result by creating a `(s/stream 10)`, and using `(try-put! msg 0)` instead of just `put!`, such any puts to a full stream will immediately time out.